# Selenium Webdriver, scrolling inside a div popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a pop that is displayed which has a content that large that will have to scroll to view it completely. Is there was to scroll the content within the div that is shown as a popup. We can use the JavaScriptExecutor to do scroll to Element, but that seems to work only at the window level but not at the div level.

Answer (score 10):

```
// Initialize Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// Scroll inside web element vertically (e.g. 100 pixel)
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.id("<div-id>")), 100);
```

This should help to scroll within DIV element.

Comment: How would we scroll horizontally in this example?

Comment: @RayzorK For Horizontal scroll, please use **scrollLeft** method. Example will look like this: `js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.id("<div-id>")), 100);`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go. Is there anywhere these commands are documented?

Comment: That is great! Thank you @mfsi_sitamj

Comment: Happy to be able to help.