# Scroll down on the terms and condition Textbox and click on Agree selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am working on Protractor tests. Recently my web page changed where the terms and conditions are inside a textbox. Button Submit works only when the user scrolls through the textbox and clicks on Agree button. I tried the following option to scroll down but it is not scrolling down. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var scrollbar = element(by.id('terms-conditions'));
var checkbox = element(by.id('checkbox'));

scrollbar.click()

browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', scrollbar.getWebElement());
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,670);')
checkbox.click();
```

I followed the below link too but no luck.

[Protractor: Scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571852/protractor-scroll-down/23573893#23573893)

Comment: You should try to reach check box element then click as `browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', checkbox);
checkbox.click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second js execute statement you are using contains `Window.scrollTo`  which references  an open window in a browser. and using it only scrolls the complete window but not the pop-ups that appear inside a browser window
Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) for documentation on `Window.scrollTo`

Normally terms and conditions shows up in a pop-up or may be a div and hence `Window.scrollTo` doesn't work

there are two ways you can do it

SOLUTION 1: use Jquery scrollTop() to scroll inside a specific webElement

Step 1: Identify the exact div that holds your terms of Service scroll bar

Step 2: Refine your js statement by trying directly in Chrome console

`$('.modal-body').scrollTop()` -> This returns the current position of scroll
`$('.modal-body').scrollTop(10000)` -> This sets the value of top position

Step 3: Incorporate this in your protractor script

```
browser.executeScript('$('.modal-body').scrollTop(10000)');
```

You can professionalize this by passing the element & scroll amount as arguments. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709200/selenium-webdriver-scrolling-inside-a-div-popup)

SOLUTION 2; The best way I see to submit a pop-up is not to deal with interface but to deal with the 'form' element behind it. Similar to how we deal with file uploads.No fuss & effective

May be try something like this, by making button visible first and then submit form

Answer (score 0):

`browser.executeScript` is an asynchronous call, so you will need to put it into the `controlFlow` so that it will complete before clicking the checkbox:

```
scrollbar.click();
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', scrollbar.getWebElement());
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,670);');
});
checkbox.click();
```

Comment: Still the textbox scroll bar is not scrolling down :(