# Scroll down a dropdown (igCombo) element one page at a time, until it reaches end of list

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an igCombo dropdown control that uses virtualization to load the items into the HTML from the javascript. Upon initial expansion of the dropdown, the full list of items are not in the list/HTML, only about the first 10 items are. As the user scrolls down, new items get loaded into the HTML. So I cant simply use SelecElement.SelectByText, or I cant use a simple function to store all li elements inside a for loop from the HTML, because if the item I want to click on is at index 11 or further, it wont be inside the HTML yet.

I think the only way to attack this is to use a for loop to store the initial items in the HTML. Then if the user-passed itemToClick variable value matches any items in this for loop, click on that item, else scroll down one full page to load the next 10 items. Repeat loop until itemToClick value matches any of the items after scrolling, or until the scroll reaches the bottom of the dropdown, and then at that point, tell the user that the item is not there.

So my method call is here. Note that I want to click on "MTV", which is at the bottom of the list in the dropdown:

```
ClickListItemByNameVirtualization(driver, dropDownElem, scrollBarElem, "MTV");
```

Here is the method. See the **NOT CODED YET** comments. That is what I need help with. I tried a couple things, but I cant come up with code that works for what I need:

```
public void ClickListItemByNameVirtualization(IWebDriver browser, IWebElement divElemOfScrollBar, IWebElement ulElemOfDropDown, string itemName)
{
    bool topOfList = true;

    do
    {
        if (topOfList == false)
        {
            // NOT CODED YET: I need a method that scrolls down page by page within a dropdown frame. For reference of how I scroll statically inside a
            // frame, see my ScrollToWithinFrame method that I referenced at the bottom of this post
            ScrollDownPageWithinDropdown();
        }

        topOfList = false;

        // Store all li elements within the unordered list
        var liElems = ulElemOfDropDown.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();

        // Loop through all list items
        foreach (var liElem in liElems)
        {
            // if the current list item's text value in the for loop equals the users passed parameter itemName
            if (liElem.Text == itemName)
            {
                liElem.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(0200);
                return;
            }
        }
        // NOT CODED YET: I need code to add to ScrollBarEnd that returns true or false. Only do the above code if ScrollBarEnd is false
    } while (!ScrollBarEnd());
}
```

And finally, for reference, here is my code to scroll within frames:

```
public void ScrollToWithinFrame(IWebDriver browser, IWebElement divElemOfScrollBar, int xOrYCoordinate, string HorizontalOrVertical)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)browser;

    if (HorizontalOrVertical == "Vertical")
    {
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];", divElemOfScrollBar, xOrYCoordinate);
    }

    if (HorizontalOrVertical == "Horizontal")
    {
        // Scroll inside the popup frame element vertically. See the following...
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709200/selenium-webdriver-scrolling-inside-a-div-popup
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];", divElemOfScrollBar, xOrYCoordinate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a infinite loop with a waiter waiting for a new `<li>` element at the end of the list:

```
public void ClickListItemByNameVirtualization(IWebDriver browser, IWebElement divElemOfScrollBar, IWebElement ulElemOfDropDown, string itemName)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    IWebElement lastLi = null;

    while (true) {

        // wait for a new li element at the end and store all li elements
        var liElems = wait.Until<ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>(drv => {

            var elems = ulElemOfDropDown.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

            return (elems.Count > 0 && elems[elems.Count - 1] != lastLi) ? elems : null;
        });

        // store the last element
        lastLi = liElems[liElems.Count - 1];

        // Loop through all list items
        foreach (var liElem in liElems) {
            // if the current list item's text value in the for loop equals the users passed parameter itemName
            if (liElem.Text == itemName) {
                liElem.Click();
                return;
            }
        }

        // scroll the container to the end
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).js.ExecuteScript(
          "arguments[0].scrollTop = (-1 >>> 1);", divElemOfScrollBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This may work, but your javascript to scroll is scrolling to the end of the list for me. There is no code to scroll page by page

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an ugly way to do it. Since I know the visible height of the scroll bar when expanded, which contains the visible items (Items that are loaded into the HTML at 10 per scroll), I use that visible height (387 pixels) to scroll on each step of my for loop until I reach the max height. Here it is. I wont mark this as the answer until 2 days, to possibly give someone else a try that has something more intuitive.

```
public static void ClickListItemByNameVirtualization(IWebDriver browser, IWebElement ulElem, IWebElement divElem, string itemName)
        int scrollAmount = 0;
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)browser;

        ProgramLibraryPage PL = new ProgramLibraryPage(browser);
        PL.ChangeProgFormSelectProgDrpDnBtn.Click();

        // Scroll to the top of the list
        js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].scrollTop = 0;", divElem);


        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            List<IWebElement> liElems = ulElem.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();

            foreach (var liElem in liElems)
            {
                // if the current list item's text value in the for loop equals the users passed parameter itemName
                if (liElem.Text == itemName)
                {
                    liElem.Click();
                    Thread.Sleep(0200);
                    return;
                }
            }

            scrollAmount = scrollAmount + 387;

            object scrollMaxHeight = js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", divElem);

            var scrollMaxHeightInt = Convert.ToInt32(scrollMaxHeight);

            if (scrollMaxHeightInt > scrollAmount)
            {
                ElemSet.ScrollToWithinFrame(browser, divElem, scrollAmount, "Vertical");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you can try using following: `js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", lastElem);` where `lastElem` is your current last element in the drop-down list.